# About the Gaussian curvature of the secant surface between two curves

Tags: differential-geometry

Given $\alpha(t)$ and $\beta(t)$ two differentialble vector functions with common domain I, we define the secant surface between the two resulting curves by:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol X(t,u)=(1-u) \boldsymbol\alpha(t)+ u \boldsymbol\beta(t)
\end{equation}
for $(t,u) \in I \times \mathbb{R}$. Assume that the corresponding surface is regular. How can I prove that the Gaussian curvature is zero fore any point with $u=\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Here details of my computation:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol X_{t,u}(t,u)=\boldsymbol \beta^{'}(t)-\boldsymbol \alpha^{'}(t)
\end{equation}
While the normal vector N is by definition:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol N_{t,u}(t,u)=\frac{\boldsymbol X_t(t,u) \times \boldsymbol X_u(t,u)}{||\boldsymbol X_t(t,u) \times\boldsymbol X_u(t,u)||}
\end{equation}
Now:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol X_t(t,u) \times \boldsymbol X_u(t,u)=(1-u) \boldsymbol \alpha^{'}(t) \times   \boldsymbol \beta(t)-(1-u) \boldsymbol \alpha^{'}(t) \times   \boldsymbol \alpha(t)+u  \boldsymbol \beta^{'}(t) \times   \boldsymbol \beta(t)-u  \boldsymbol \beta{'}(t) \times   \boldsymbol \alpha(t)
\end{equation}
The mixed product after few computation reduces to:
\begin{equation}
( \boldsymbol X_t(t,u) \times \boldsymbol X_u(t,u)) \cdot \boldsymbol X_{t,}(t,u)=  \boldsymbol \alpha^{'}(t) \cdot (\boldsymbol \beta^{'}(t) \times (\alpha(t)- \beta(t)) )
\end{equation}
If the mixed product is zero, the three vectors are linearly dependent, i.e. two of the three vectors are parallel.

The Gaussian curvature, when secant surface is as specified above, is zero if $\boldsymbol N \cdot \boldsymbol X_{t,u}=0$, where $\boldsymbol N$ is the normal vector. However $\boldsymbol N \cdot \boldsymbol X_{t,u}$ is independent of $u$.

Comment: The result you're trying to prove seems very wrong. You can easily make a hyperboloid of one sheet (with $K<0$) by taking $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be parallel circles, parametrized with a phase shift.

Comment: Hi Ted, I agree with you. I think that the Gaussaian curvature is not zero for all points with $u=\frac{1}{2}$. However this is a problem from the boot Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces by Thomas F. Banchoff, Stephen T. Lovett.

Comment: I stand by my statement. However, your argument is flawed, I think. $\mathbf X_{t,u}$ is independent of $u$, but $\mathbf N$ is not.

Comment: It is the dot product of N and $X_{t,y}$ which is independent of u.

Comment: Write down the formula for $\mathbf N$. At any rate, I still think the problem is false as stated. For the hyperboloid I mentioned above, we in fact have maximum Gaussian curvature when $u=1/2$.

Comment: I agree with you. When adding the denominator, $\mathbf N$ depends on $u$. I didn't include the denominator because the problem asked to prove that the Gaussian curvature is zero for any point with  $u=\frac{1}{2}$, then when the numerator is zero. The problem ask to prove that the Gaussian curvature is zero if and only if $u=\frac{1}{2}$ of $\mathbf{\beta}-\mathbf{\alpha}$ is in the plane spanned by $\mathbf{\beta^{'}}$ and $\mathbf{\alpha^{'}}$. It's quite easy to prove the coplanarity, but concerning $u=\frac{1}{2}$ I think there is an error in the textbook.

Comment: Yes, I believe they messed up the arithmetic keeping track of signs (getting $1-u-u$ rather than $1-u+u$). My original counterexample ought to be completely convincing that they were wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the denominator in $\mathbf N$, so even though your scalar triple product is independent of $u$, the actual entry of the second fundamental form is not. As I suggested in the comments, the secant surface is ruled and you should not expect it to have points of zero Gaussian curvature. However, when your scalar triple product is $0$, the surface will be developable, i.e., everywhere flat. This will happen, for example, when $\boldsymbol\alpha$ and $\boldsymbol\beta$ are parallel circles, parametrized in synch (so the secant surface is a cylinder), when $\boldsymbol\beta$ is a constant path (so the secant surface is a cone), or when $\boldsymbol\alpha$ and $\boldsymbol\beta$ both lie in the same plane.

P.S. Textbooks do have erroneous exercises (or even theorems) from time to time. I should know. :)